# Flutter - How to clip an arc container?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to implement effect like pic below.
[image]

I have a rect container(width:400, height:100), I want to clip the blue area of the rect, so I can get the orange area.
Attention,
The orange arc is tangent to the bottom line .
 Could you give the details code?

Comment: Use [CustomClipper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html) to get your satisfactory output.

Comment: Refer [this](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/custom-clipping-in-flutter-8aa0631ef19b) article for a better understanding.

Comment: @SanketPatel CustomClipper is right. But I do not how to set the controller point to let the orange arc is tangent to the bottom line?

Comment: Take a point at (200,100) it will create an automatic arc with the tangent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Custom Clipper class , to get this type of shape I will share an example code you can change values according to your need

```
class ClipPathClass extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double radius = 50;
    var path = Path();

    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 30);

    var firstControlPoint = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height);
    var firstPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy,
        firstPoint.dx, firstPoint.dy);

    var secondControlPoint = Offset(size.width - (size.width / 4), size.height);
    var secondPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height - 30);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(secondControlPoint.dx, secondControlPoint.dy,
        secondPoint.dx, secondPoint.dy);

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width - radius, 0);

    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

then use this ClipPathClass() like ,

```
ClipPath(
  clipper: ClipPathClass(),
child: Container(width:400,height: 100,color:Colors.grey)
)
```